# distinguish between bodies in Catia

Tags: vba, catia

How to distinguish between bodies in Catia (i.e name of the 2 bodies can be the same) and there are no other properties in the properties tab. Is it possible to distinguish using catvba?

[image: The image shows the properties tab]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Therefor you can read (with undocumented methods) the internal name of a feature/object (which can not be changed):

```vb
Dim oModelElement As Object
Dim sInternalName As String

Set oModelElement = oBody.GetItem("ModelElement")
sInternalName = oModelElement.InternalName

MsgBox sInternalName
```

Comment: thankyou, This is a good bit of information, but I need to distinguish between bodies, not between model elements. (or) I am not understanding it properly.

Comment: If both bodies have the same name, you can compare their internal name. Maybe explain when you have to distinguish these bodies. How do you access these bodies?

Comment: Hello Shrotter, if i have internal name can i select a body with it?

Comment: Try Method _FindObjectByName_ from the Part. You already have the body (before reading the internal name), why don't you use this object/body?